# Unique Rows for a cell array

Tags: matlab, unique, cell, cell-array, strcat

I am wondering how can one find unique rows of a cell array when considering only the second and sixth columns of it.

I tried this already: `a = unique(strcat(a(:,2), a(:, 6)),'rows')`, where `a` is the cell array, but it gives an error - `index exceeds matrix dimensions)`.

I tried to use the functions `unique` and `strcat` because they work for cell type variables with both strings and numbers .

Comment: I tried this already: `a = unique(strcat(a(:,2), a(:, 6)),'rows');` but it gives an error (index exceeds matrix dimensions)

Comment: What's `a`?  Please provide a (small) reproducible example by editing your question

Comment: @user3557054 Made few edits, please check those out if they make more sense now.

Comment: @user3557054 Also as mentioned in Dennis's solution, since you mentioned - `index exceeds matrix dimensions)`, you need to see if you have consistent data along the columns 2 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `a` to be the cell array and that you are looking to find unique rows off it based on the column `2` and `6` cells. For the same, one approach based on few `unique` usages could be suggested, as shown next -

```
[~,~,ind1] = unique(cellfun(@num2str,a(:,2),'uni',0)) %//unique indices for col 2
[~,~,ind2] = unique(cellfun(@num2str,a(:,6),'uni',0)) %//unique indices for col 6
[~,ind]= unique([ind1 ind2],'rows','stable')%//unique row indices based on col2,6
a = a(ind,:)
```

Another approach to shave off one `unique` -

```
col26 = cellfun(@num2str,[a(:,2) a(:,6)],'uni',0)
[~,~,unqind26] = unique(col26(:))
col26indexed = reshape(unqind26,size(col26))
[~,ind] = unique(col26indexed,'rows','stable')
a = a(ind,:)
```

Notice the use of `num2str` as `unique` for cell arrays only works with cells of strings, so they had to be converted to `strings`.

Both of these approaches would work with a `cell array` of `numerals` or `strings` or a `mix of them` (assuming `[0]` and `'0'` to be the same), but if you would like to have the "uniqueness" based on their datatypes too, then more codes have to added there and since that specific case is not mentioned in the question, it is not considered here.

Also, I don't think you need to use `strcat` here from what I understood reading the text of the question.

Comment: I agree that `strcat` does not appear neccesary, but it appears the solution does not work or explain the error. Try it with this cell array: `a = cell(6); a(:)={0}; a(1,2)={1}`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks! That was a good bug find there, as I missed out on testing with `cell array of numerals`, which is fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

I see only three possible ways here to generate the error that you get.

1. The varible `a` is too small or called incorrectly. Test this by running `a(:,6)` separately.
2. Accidentally you created a variable named `strcat`
3. Accidentally you created a variable called `unique`

I am not sure whether 2 and 3 can actually lead to the error that you get, but number 1 is the most likely suspect.